# Instal and setup IKEv2/IPsec on WD PR4100

Tags: vpn, nas, busybox

I have a WD PR4100 NAS and would like to set up a IKEv2/IPsec VPN tunnel. Currently, I am using OpenVPN as it is installed.

I believe the system is BusyBox based. Any suggestions on how to install the package dependencies and set up the connection? Specifically, I am trying to connect with [this tutorial](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/ikev2ipsec/). I am currently looking into docker implementations. However, it will be better if I can natively install and set up the connection instead of using a docker.

The only docker I have found that can act as a client (others only act as servers) is [this](https://github.com/Stanback/alpine-strongswan-vpn), although when I edit the files as in the above [tutorial](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/ikev2ipsec/), and then run

```
docker rm strongswan; docker run --net=host -v $PWD/config/strongswan.conf:/etc/strongswan.conf -v $PWD/config/ipsec.conf:/etc/ipsec.conf -v $PWD/config/ipsec.secrets:/etc/ipsec.secrets -v $PWD/config/ipsec.d:/etc/ipsec.d --name=strongswan stanback/alpine-strongswan-vpn
```

I get the following output

```
Starting strongSwan 5.6.1 IPsec [starter]...
modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
no netkey IPsec stack detected
modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
no KLIPS IPsec stack detected
no known IPsec stack detected, ignoring!
00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.6.1, Linux 4.1.13, x86_64)
00[KNL] unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported (93)
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] enabling UDP decapsulation for IPv6 on port 4500 failed
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] enabling UDP decapsulation for IPv4 on port 4500 failed
00[LIB] feature CUSTOM:libcharon in critical plugin 'charon' has unmet dependency: CUSTOM:kernel-ipsec
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
00[KNL] unable to create IPv4 routing table rule
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
00[KNL] unable to create IPv6 routing table rule
00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
00[LIB]   file coded in unknown format, discarded
00[LIB] building CRED_CERTIFICATE - X509 failed, tried 4 builders
00[CFG]   loading ca certificate from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts/caCert.pem' failed
00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
00[CFG]   loaded EAP secret for kazoku@protonmail.com
00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
00[LIB] failed to load 1 critical plugin feature
00[DMN] initialization failed - aborting charon
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
charon has quit: initialization failed
charon refused to be started
ipsec starter stopped
```

Apart from this I do not know if it is even possible to install everything separately and not use a docker as the BusyBox based system is limited from what I can see.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried something and experienced a problem or encountered an error?

Comment: @music2myear I've added what I have tried.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`? That'll give you the full Linux version, processor architecture, ...

Comment: @Fabby `Linux ------------ 4.1.13 #1 SMP Thu Nov 30 19:20:59 CST 2017 Build-gitdf6634a x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Too bad about the bounty: I cannot help you any further, but if you wouldn't find an answer here, delete it here or ask a moderator to migrate it to [linux.se].

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by running the container with the `--privileged` flag